# Including a local version of a library that failed to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to take a screenshot of a page every five minutes, and it works correctly most of the time. The problem is that sometimes the page I am taking a screenshot of fails to load the AngularJS library, and then, it can't build the page after that. So I am trying to figure out how to load a local copy in its place. Here is what I have been trying...

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),system = require('system');
var home = 'https://smartway.tn.gov/traffic/';

page.open(home, function (status) {
    if(status === "success"){
        page.injectJs('angular.js');
        window.setTimeout((function() {
            page.evaluate(function () {
                /*stuff*/
            });
        }), 2000);
    }
});
```

So angular.js is the name of my local copy of what the site would normally download. The site calls the script at the end of the body with several other scripts, and I am trying to find the best way to include it. I am wondering if it needs to be included by replacing the script tag in the html so it can be loaded in sequence, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is problematic to reload a single JavaScript file when it failed, particularly when it is the framework. There are probably many scripts which depend on it. When the core framework is not loaded, those scripts will stop executing, because the `angular` reference cannot be resolved.

You *could* inject a local version of angular, but then you would have to go over all the other scripts which reference `angular` and "reload" them by either downloading and `eval`ing them in order or putting them into the page as script elements. I advise against it, because it is probably very error prone.

You should just reload the page if angular does not exist after page load (callback of `page.open`). Since the same problem may occurr during reload, this has to be done recursively:

```
function open(countDown, done){
    if (countDown === 0) {
        done("ERROR: not loaded");
        return;
    }
    page.open(home, function (status) {
        if(status === "success"){
            var angularExists = page.evaluate(function () {
                return !!angular;
            });
            if (angularExists){
                done();
            } else {
                open(countDown - 1, done);
            }
        } else {
            open(countDown - 1, done);
        }
    });
}
open(5, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        page.render(target);
    }
});
```

You can also try the [`page.reload()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/reload.html) function instead of a `page.open()`.

---

The other possiblity is to always inject the local version when the page loading began and stop any request for the remote version of the script:

```
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    page.injectJs('angular.js');
};
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    var match = requestData.url.match(/angular\.min\.js/g);
    if (match != null) {
        networkRequest.abort(); 
    }
};
page.open(home, function (status) {
    if(status === "success"){
        window.setTimeout((function() {
            page.evaluate(function () {
                /*stuff*/
            });
        }), 2000);
    }
});
```

This version works entirely without reloading.

Comment: Hey Artjom, thanks for the response. You have single-handedly answered just about every question I have looked up while trying to learn PhantomJS. The problem with this solution is that on the server I am running this from, it fails more often than not. Our IT department is looking at why the files from this website don't download 75% of the time, but for now, the script is working by injecting the local copy onInitialized. Is there a way to just delete their script call and just use my local copy?

Comment: Yes, there should be another way, because you can abort requests in PhantomJS. I thought that injecting a script from `page.onInitialized` doesn't work in this case, so I added a version with `page.onLoadStarted`. See my updated answer.